# Rolewise status display on Bugzilla

Tags: web, privacy, bugzilla

I have two roles in bugzilla .
1 . Admin
2.  Developers.

Now my requirement is, showing some chosen workflow status to the developers not all. This way I will allow developers to change some statuses(IN PROGRESS / RESOLVED) but not allow to CLOSE or ASSIGN the bug.

How should I configure it in Bugzilla ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also an Admin of Bugzilla. You can set the **Group access** of developers like this. [image: bugzilla-developer-account]

In this way, they just can change the bug's status to *Resolve* and then you can *close* them after rechecking.